# Finding size of binary tree without traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am working on an assignment for class in which we are given a binary tree that has been numbered by pre/post/in order traversal. We must write a size method that computes in constant time O(1).

From what I understand is that when you traverse a binary tree it costs O(n) time because each node is checked. So clearly I must find the size of this tree without traversing it.

For post-order this is easy because the size is simply the value of the root + 1, but for the other two methods I don't see how it can be computed without traversing.

ASSIGNMENT QUESTION VERBATIM

2. Suppose we are given a binary tree with pre-order, post-order, and in-order numbers assigned to the
   nodes. Show (on paper) how these numbers can be used to answer each of the following questions in
   constant time:
   a. Given a node u, determine the size of the subtree rooted at u.
   b. Given a node u, determine the depth of u.
   c. Given two nodes u and w, determine if u is an ancestor of w.

Comment: Have you considered just keeping track of the size, incrementing and decrementing as you add and delete items?

Comment: That would be the easy solution for sure. However we are required to write the size method that calculates based on a given Node U, so unfortunately I can't do it :/

Comment: Cannot be done.  Please post all relevant *and* pertinent code, (excluding any unnecessary stuff,) as well as the precise wording of the assignment.  Please include your solution for post-order.

Comment: Can't be done unless you maintain the size of each subtree in each node.

Comment: I read the assignment as you are given _all three_ numbers for each node. If so, you already demonstrated how to find a size; the rest is equally trivial.